# How do I delete a SQL Server database that is inside a Docker container?

Tags: sql-server, database, docker

Long time no post! My question is as the title says - how to delete a SQL Server database inside a docker container.

Scenario: I am on a MacBook Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.4 running Docker 18.03.0-ce-mac60 (23751)

I followed the instructions to set up SQL Server 2017 inside a Docker container at the following link [(Setting up SQL Server in Docker on a Mac)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-linux-2017) and now have a database running.

But now I want to delete the database and rebuild it again. I don't really care for the data inside it, I just want to get rid of the database without necessary deleting the container and just create a new DB using the SQL Server instance.

I am aware that it may involve using the `sqlcmd` tool from within Docker, but I am unsure of the particular parameters required, and I cannot find much information on the process otherwise..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you followed the guide exactly as it is -

1. Open a new terminal in your container:

Using bash:

> ```
> sudo docker exec -it sql1 "bash"
> ```

OR PowerShell

> ```
> docker exec -it sql1 "bash"
> ```

2. Connect to sqlcmd using your original query:

> ```
> /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourNewStrong!Passw0rd>'
> ```

3. Next run the command to drop/delete your database:

> ```
> DROP DATABASE TestDB;
> ```

3. Commit your changes:

> ```
> GO;
> ```

Comment: Thanks @scandalous ! The only change I had to adjust was connecting to the bash shell in docker as root, as I could not delete the database without proper permissions, so I connected with the following minor adjustment instead

`sudo docker exec -u root -it container-name "bash"`

cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/delete-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) to delete your database:

```
USE master ;  
GO  
DROP DATABASE Sales, NewSales ;  
GO
```

Comment: Thanks, my challenge was to use that similar command *within* the docker container. I had an issue of actually launching sqlcmd (or tsql) within the container shell in order to perform the DROP command. thanks for you comment!